# Overfull \hbox leads to "Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"

Tags: errors

I was writing my thesis and after compiling this message error popped out:

> "Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"

I removed all the image code I wrote, saved and compiled; removed the entire chapter but it keeps showing this message. Honestly, I don't know what I can do.

Here is the log file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B70UvyhcigbbMzFYNThLS1JPZkk

I really hope, someone can help me

```
Overfull \hbox (37.4907pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 18--18
 []  
 []

./Tesi.lof:18: pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode
.
\close@pdflink ...\Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink 

l.18 ...ine]{aggiustare figura} }}{30}{figure.2.9}
```

Comment: I inserted the interesting part of the log file - at least I think it is.

Comment: Thank you... The strange part is that I erased that part of the code! But it seems like it's still there

Comment: Please delete all of the output files (like `aux bbl lof` and so on). Keep basically only the tex files.

Comment: THX SO MUCH, I don't really know how I can say you thank you. :)

Comment: If you want than you can accept the answer by clicking on check mark on the left side of the answer. I have a tutorial showing the first steps including the deletion of the files like in your case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4uIAOPq1UE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Delete everything except the `tex` file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the pretty much the same problem, after spending the last few hours trying to solve it, i've found that my antivirus antiransom tool was not allowing the pdf file to be edited, because the file was located in the protected directory by the ransomware. I deactivated that specific antivirus tool and it worked, it is also possible to select the specific directories to protect, dont know much about the software anyway, i hope this is useful to someone:)